# renumbering a column using date as reference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an `ind` column with almost random values:
`3 - 200 - 142 - ...`

I need to change it this way:
`1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - ...` using `date` (datetime) column as reference.

So, in the end, order by `date` and order by `ind` would give the same ordering.

Any help?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Wierd request this sounds to me you are destroying the "connection" between the `ind` and `date` columns

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do:

```
set @i := 0;

update t
    set ind = (@i := @i + 1)
    order by date;
```